# Fastest way to filter collection in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model that I am trying to filter by multiple columns (some may not be present in the filter) and am trying to speed up this query.

Here is a snippet of the index method of the controller:

```
def index
    @things = Thing.accessible_by(current_ability)

    if params.has_key?(:color)
      @things = @things.where(:color => params[:color])
    end

    if params.has_key?(:weight)
      @things = @things.where(:weight => params[:weight])
    end

    if params.has_key?(:size)
      @things = @things.where(:size => params[:size])
    end

    @things = @things.order(:updated_at).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])

end
```

I have added these indexes:

```
add_index :things, :color
add_index :things, :weight
add_index :things, :size
```

Trying to figure out the fastest way to do this.  Also want to add results to a cache keyed by concatenation of params passed in, that make sense to add?  The cache will only help with subsequent filters though, not the initial one.

Thanks

Comment: How long is the query taking, and how long do you think it should take? What is the `EXPLAIN` output?

Comment: With 350 things query takes ~580ms. Oh interesting, looks like its only 40ms in active record but 500ms in rendering the json :(

Comment: Don't be sad—it's always good when you understand your problem better than you did before! Happily, [much has been written](https://www.google.com/search?q=speed+up+rails+json+rendering) about speeding up JSON rendering in Rails. (Just make sure any advice you take still applies to Rails 4.)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really about speeding up your query, but something to reduce the size of your action

```
def index
    filtered_params = params.select{|x| [:color, :weight, :size].include? x}
    @things = Thing.accessible_by(current_ability)
               .where(filtered_params)
               .order(:updated_at)
               .page(params[:page])
               .per(params[:per_page])
end
```

Also you might want to consider caching the views, would help if your views don't change that much.